# Can we automate IBM Mobile First Platform Apps using Appium?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

Currently, I am working on testing IBM Mobile First Platform Applications for Android. We are testing the apps on multiple testing tools. Though we have IBM Mobile First Test Workbench, I want to test it on other tools too.

So I have tried it testing using Appium. But the problem is, it shows the resource id is missing.

I have tried to solve the issue. But nothing seems to work for me.

So I need to know that Is Appium supported for Mobile First Apps. If yes then is there any way to solve my issue.

I am developing apps on Mobile First Platform 7.0 and developing apps with JQuery Mobile 1.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation-based Hybrid/Native apps are not supported, or at least were never tested with, Appium.

Feel free to submit a feature request: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help